# Failed to read scan data : Argument list too long

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4 version and when i run following command

**/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan**

I see below error always

```
root@automation01:~# /sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Argument list too long
```

iwconfig output looks like below

[iwconfig output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzI7J.png)

Answer (score 8):

Same here, check if using `iw` insead works. For me, `iw` is returning the scan data fine but `iwlist` is not.

```
iw wlan0 scan
```

I'm getting it only in some physical locations (at school which has some weird setups).